# Is it possible to see table in mongodb like in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know that this is not good question but i am asking please help me any suggestion or solution .Is it possible to see the tables,
structure and data like phpmyadmin or parse.com provide the GUI.

I install the mongodb in my Ubuntu OS but i fetch the data through queries. Is it possible to use a tool like GUI based application so that i can see the data,table structure and other information.

i am new in mongodb if there is any solution to setup the gui based application that can interact with mongodb like MySQL and phpmyadmin 
please provide the relevant information.

thanks

Comment: When you are new to MongoDB, here is my suggestion: Do not use a GUI at all. You will neither learn MongoDB any better nor does it help you to understand. Any "magic" is actively acting as an obstacle for learning how things work.

Comment: Besides that: Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Questions for suggested software are explicitly off-topic and belong to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com However, please do not double post. Be so kind to remove your question here before asking there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't beat [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/).  It's free, reliable and intuitive.  Exactly what you want.

Comment: now called Robo3T, but still pretty awesome and the link still works.

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/) is a GUI for MongoDB.